# UISwipeGestureRecognizer on UITableView subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll, uiswipegesturerecognizer

|

```
---- self.view
```

|

```
-------- UIView (A)
```

|

```
------------ UITableView
```

|

```
---------------- UIView (B)
```

|

I've this hierarchy, added `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on `UIView` (B), I've given all four directions for the swipe gesture, however it could only detects left and right directions, when I tried for up and down side swipe `UITableView` scrolls, what should I do to recognize swipe instead of doing table scroll?

I did the following (individually) after googled, but it wont work.

```
swipeUp.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; //swipeUp is UISwipeGestureRecognizer

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

I can't disable/enable table scrolling as there're other views to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `TableView` scrolling while showing View B by:

```
 table.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

This will prevent the table view to scroll. Don't forget to enable `tableview` scrolling after hiding view B. For this you need to do is:

```
 table.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

**EDIT:**

You can have a look at

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

From this delegate you can determine the gesture is working on which view. Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361781/how-to-reliably-find-correct-view-for-uigesturerecognizer).

Hope this help. :)

Comment: Good trick! But I can't do that, because I've other views in table.